# Do I need to build a custom UITableViewCell for this?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I'm quite new to ipod programming, so be patient lol.

Im trying to have buttons in a cellView that will have one of 2 values for each cell, a + and a -. Meaning, the button will show +, when you click it, it jumps to -.

I've managed to get the buttons to work and change the underlying data, but I'm running in to trouble when redrawing the table.

I added as a comment where I need to change the text for the button to the source code. Can this be done, or do I have to build a custom uitableviewcell?

Tia, Stefano.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    //some code

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             SectionsTableIdentifier ];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIImage *buttonUpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_up.png"];
        UIImage *buttonDownImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_down.png"];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonUpImage.size.width, buttonUpImage.size.height);
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonUpImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonDownImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        if (some condition) [button setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        else [button setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryView = button;
    }
    if (someCondition) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"text1";
    }else {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"text2";
    }

    //I NEED TO CHANGE THE TEXT FOR THE BUTTON HERE.

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're making the button the cell's accessoryView, you can do this:

```
UIButton *accButton = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView;
[accButton setTitle:@"New Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Comment: Oh, I missed this answer or I wouldn't've posted mine. Upticked.

Comment: Accepted this answer over Steven´s just because it was posted earlier.
Works perfectly, thanks a lot. Learning Objective-C and the Iphone API at the same time is kind of overwhelming sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

`cell` is usually not going to be nil, which means your cell setup code will usually be skipped. You need to make sure that your per-cell setup code is **not** in the condition, but in the code that follows it.

So something like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

    //some code

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:
                             SectionsTableIdentifier ];
    if (cell == nil) {

        // Note that here, we set up only the things that will not change.

        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
                                       reuseIdentifier:SectionsTableIdentifier] autorelease];
        UIImage *buttonUpImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_up.png"];
        UIImage *buttonDownImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button_down.png"];
        UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonUpImage.size.width, buttonUpImage.size.height);
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonUpImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button setBackgroundImage:buttonDownImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryView = button;
    }

    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)cell.accessoryView; // get button back, regardless of if we went through init above
    if (someCondition) {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"text1";
        [button setTitle:@"+" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }else {
        cell.textLabel.text = @"text2";
        [button setTitle:@"-" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 
    }

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Correct answer, I didnt mark it because aBitObvious posted first. Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's cool. I wouldn't've posted mine if I'd seen that one first anyway. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the text in the same way that you're setting the background image - you have to set it for a particular control state.

If you just try to change myButton.text it will not show up.

The right code is therefore:

```
 [button setText:@"Some Text" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have also problems when scrolling table up and down. All cells have the same identifier and they will be reused on refreshing. This means that cell will not always be nil. So the accessory button title should be updated after the condition: `if (cell == nil) {}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to move the code setting the button's text down to where your comment is. Your problem here is to get access to the button, which you don't have a pointer to. One approach is to assign a tag to the button when setting up the cell, and requesting the subview with that tag to obtain that cell later.

The better method would be to use a custom table view cell, as you indicate. It isn't much work, and you can access its content directly if you provide a property. Also, you might push that logic for state changes down into that class.